# Error in your SQL syntax - c# - MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I know this is probably something very simple I messed up.  Can anyone tell me where I went wrong with my Replace Command Text?

```
cmd.CommandText = $"UPDATE `{dataTableName}` " +
                    "SET (`entry`, `zone`, `x_axis`, `y_axis`, `z_axis`, `situation`, `faction`, `type`) " +
                    "VALUES (@Entry, @Zone, @X, @Y, @Z, @Situation, @Faction, @Type)" +
                    "WHERE zone = @Zone AND x_axis = @X AND y_axis = @Y";
//Add data value with Parameters.
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entry", entry);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zone", zone);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@X", x);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Y", y);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Z", z);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Situation", situation);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", type);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Faction", faction);
```

Comment: There's no space before WHERE

Comment: Right for the WHERE, but the UPDATE syntax is totally different: UPDATE table SET field1=Value1, field2=Value2 .....

Comment: John -> Unfortunately that did not fix it, although you are correct so there was 2 problems!

Steve -> I will try that.

Comment: Steve you were dead on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space before the `where` is not the issue.  The problem is the list of columns.  MySQL requires `set col = val, . . .` for the syntax.  Some databases (such as Oracle) do allow lists of columns, but even those do not use a `VALUES` keyword.

So, structure the code like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = $"UPDATE `{dataTableName}`" +
                    " SET `entry` = @Entry, `z_axis` = @Z, . . ." +
                    " WHERE zone = @Zone AND x_axis = @X AND y_axis = @Y";
```

Note also that you do not need to set `zone`, `x_axis`, and `y_axis` because the `where` clause requires that these already have the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer for this was:
1) My SET syntax was completely wrong.

Here is the WORKING code

```
cmd.CommandText = $"UPDATE `{dataTableName}` " +
                    "SET entry = @Entry, zone = @Zone, x_axis = @X, y_axis = @Y, z_axis = @Z, " +
                    "situation = @Situation, faction = @Faction, type = @Type " +
                    $"WHERE zone = @Zone AND x_axis = @X AND y_axis = @Y";
```